# How does NSURLCache work in iOS 4?

Tags: ios4, nsurlcache

When I learn ***NSURLCache*** documentation I can't find many important notes.
I found that many topics in web complain that ***NSURLConnection*** that use ***NSURLCache*** had memory leaks. When I tried to write some application for iOS 4.3 I found that ***MSURLCache*** have some strange behavior.

In ***application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:*** I set instance of ***NSURLCache*** with memory capacity 10MB, init ***NSURLRequest*** with ***NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy*** but I can't recieve ***connection:willCacheResponse:*** message in my ***NSURLConnection*** delegate. When I checked memory capacity in different points of my application, it was 0MB. Why? May be Apple fix some memory leaks by setting ***NSURLCache*** memory capacity to 0? I created custom ***NSURLCache*** and overrided ***setMemoryCapacity:*** method by this:

```
-(void)setMemoryCapacity:(NSUInteger)memoryCapacity {
    if (memoryCapacity > 0) {
        [super setMemoryCapacity:memoryCapacity];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"zero here");
    }
}
```

Then I started to debug. There is some input text in my app, where user put some url. New ***setMemoryCapacity:*** method has been called twice: in my app delegate, when I set capacity to 10MB and (it is very interesting) when user set focus to text input (parameter of ***memoryCapacity*** was 0 and I recieve "zero here" string in log). After that I recieved ***connection:willCacheResponse:*** messages to ***NSURLConnection*** delegate.
It was very strange. I can't understand why. I can't find things in manual about this. Do you have some thoughts?